Websocket connection can't be established if I add /socket.io to the link
Using flask socket.io:
app = Flask(__name__)

socketio = SocketIO(app, cors_allowed_origins="*")
setSocketIo(socketio)

and angular socket.io:
this.socket = io("wss://aws-backend-ALB-url", { 
      query: {
        token: token,
        promptId: promptId
      },
      transports: ['websocket', 'polling'],  
    });

    this.socket.on('connect', () => {
      console.log('Connected to WebSocket server');
    });

I can connect with postman on wss://aws-backend-ALB-url but I can not connect on wss://aws-backend-ALB-url/socket.io (which is what I need?, because angular socket.io is adding this automatically to the wss:// url and it seems like I cant prevent this?)
Im also totally confused if socket.io is added now automatically (on the python side or/and on the angular side)
Certificate seems to work (I can connect with the same cert via https and postman does not have an issue over wss too only the url makes problems)
What can I do?
